# Is change of kubernetes limits applied to running pod?

Tags: kubernetes

If i change a ReplicationController. Is the limits applied to running pods?

If i change a Pod directly. Is the limit applied to the running Pod?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/limitrange/

Limits are only applied when a pod is created or updated. It does not apply to an already running pod.

Pod will be recreated if you change its template spec. Limit will apply to the new pod.